# How do I remove the boundaries between municipalities of my shapefile?

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, dissolve

I have a shapefile of a province right now. It includes the barangay/village boundaries and municipal boundaries. However, I only need the municipal boundaries. How will I remove the barangay/village per municipality? I tried using the merging feature in the edit menu, but it did not merge those barangays with islands as part. I also tried using the dissolve too and same results appear. What should I do?

Comment: If you only want a single type of boundary, do a query based on a relevant attribute (_boundary type = municipality_) and save the result as a new layer.

Comment: It is better to add a screenshot of how the boundaries look like.